# Control multiple login with same user name in same time in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can block second login with same userid , if first login is already exist.[session not cleared]..
i want to destroy previous session , when somebody login in somewhere with same userid . system only allow one instance with one userid.

Comment: So you don't want to block the second login? You want to allow it, but destroy the session of the previous login?

Comment: yes i dont want to block second login.. but must destroy previous session

Comment: what i need is , i developed new web site , which is a study material , for accessing this site we provide a login id for student. but i have to control only one student can enter my site with that login details at a time.

Comment: You've to store in your db : 1. If the user is logged. 2. The session id. If the login exists and is logged, so you destroy the session with the associed session id, and your re-load a new session for the new user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Many ways.

the easiest way is store the sessionid,ip address,datetime and userid in the same table.

everytime page refresh then you have to check the session id is equal to the value which we stored in database table then we have to continue.....

Now suppose user login through another system  then we have to Update that system's session in the above table.

so the previos login is not working...
In this way your problem is solved...

Thanks,
Tarun Malpani.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag maens 0 and 1. Update every time when user logs in and set its value to 1. Then when user logs out or session expires update it again and set it to zero. And when there is another attempt to log in with this id check flag status. if it is 1 then block it else allow him.